# node and express - path won't work if given from URL

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application built in express and node , the express server listens at port 2020 , there is a default.yaml file which contains a "path", if i try to modify this "path" from "url" - it doesn't works and instead gives an error "ENOENT - 404 File not found" ...

The code in default.yaml file is this :

```
cleaner:
  command: cleanJob  
  port: 2022           # internal service port. No need to allow inbound or outbound access to this port
  path: 'c:/tmp/'     # files to clear
```

Now the code in the main app file  (index.js) is this :

```
if(req.param("fpath",false)){
        var defaultPath = req.param("fpath");
    }else
    var defaultPath = cleanerService.getPath();
 var filePath = join(defaultPath, filename);
    console.log(filePath);
    var callbackUrl = req.param('callback', false) ? utils.url(req.param('callback')) : false;

    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
      cleanFilesIn(filePath, res, callbackUrl, function(err) { if (err) next(err); });
      return;
    }
```

In the above code, the `defaultPath = cleanerService.getPath()` returns the path from "default.yaml" file, now if i parse a parameter "fpath" in url to modify that path so the script instead of looking for files in the path of "default.yaml" file, uses the given "fpath"

What could be wrong with this?

Comment: Can you please share some code ?

Comment: added the code with explanation ^^